# Convert mysqli result to string directly

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying unsuccessfully to convert a single result query to string without having to write 3 lines and assign twice the same variable.
It works but I find it dirty.

Let me explain :

```
$request = $db->query("SELECT service_label FROM services WHERE id='".$infos['service']."'");  
$service = $request->fetch_assoc();
$service = $service['service_label'];
```

service.id is unique so it will always return only 1 result.
Constraints are made so $infos['service'] will ALWAYS be in the services table, therefore the query cannot fail.

I would like to end up with sort of :

```
$service = toString($db->query("SELECT service_label FROM services WHERE id='".$infos['service']."'"));
```

Is this possible ? Thanks

Comment: you should fetch object if service.id is unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $service = $db->query("SELECT service_label FROM services WHERE id='".$infos['service']."'")->fetch_object()->service_label
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
$request = current($db->query("SELECT service_label FROM services WHERE id='".$infos['service']."'")->fetch_assoc());
```